# How to delete a record from mysql database when the user closes the browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How to delete a record from mysql database when the user closes the browser.

In my application I had stored some records based on a session i want to delete those records from that tables when the user closes the browser using php.

Comment: There's no way to reliably notify the server when the user closes the browser.

Comment: you can use jquery `onbeforeunload` event. but remember there is no way to dectect when a browser is closed. This will happen whenever a redirecton occurs.T

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it easily by on ajax call via unload :) 


 $(window).unload(function() {  
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'yourprocessing-page-where-data-save-to-db.php',
               data: "",
               success: function(data) {  
               },
              });
           });​
         }
```

Comment: Its not working i used this code to check but its working $(document).ready(function() {

$(window).unload(function() {  alert("CLOSE");
});


});

Comment: check ur ajax request properly and check your processing page if request is reaching there it will work my friend

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('form').submit(function() {
    jQuery(window).unbind("beforeunload");
    ...
});
```

Comment: jQuery(window).unbind("beforeunload"); in this line what is unbind("beforeunload") will u plz xplain